# How to Subtracting 7hrs from a String time?

Tags: java

I need to convert time from GMT to PST and for that I am trying to subtract 7 hrs from the time. The issue is that the time is stored in a String and I am not sure how can I subtract 7 hrs from a String time. `displayDateString` gives me the date and time and it is a String. I am trying the following approach but it is not working the way I need it.

Before Code Change

```
 public static String formatDate(String strDate, String inputFormat, String outputFormat) {
    Date date = convertStringToDate(strDate,inputFormat);
    String displayDateString = formatDate(date, outputFormat);
    DateFormat pstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    return displayDateString;
}
```

above code outputs: `06/02/17 07:19 PM`

After Code Change

```
public static String formatDate(String strDate, String inputFormat, String outputFormat) {
    Date date = convertStringToDate(strDate,inputFormat);
    String displayDateString = formatDate(date, outputFormat);

    DateFormat pstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    /*TimeZone pstZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone( "PST" );
    pstFormat.setTimeZone( pstZone );
    displayDateString = pstFormat.format(date);*/

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add( Calendar.HOUR, -7 );
    displayDateString = pstFormat.format( cal.getTime() );
    return displayDateString;
}

public static Date convertStringToDate(String strDate, String inputFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;
    Date date = null;
    boolean formatChagned = false;
    try {
        if(!StringUtils.isSet(strDate)){
            return date;
        }
        if(strDate.indexOf("/")>0 && inputFormat.indexOf("-")>=0){
            inputFormat = inputFormat.replaceAll("-", "/");
            formatChagned=true;
        }else if (strDate.indexOf("-")>0 && inputFormat.indexOf("/")>=0){
            inputFormat = inputFormat.replaceAll("/", "-");
            formatChagned=true;
        }

        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat);
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        date = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        log.error("Given date to parse:"+strDate);
        log.error("Given Input Date Format:"+inputFormat);

        if(formatChagned){
            log.error("Given Input Date Format is incorrcet and it is modified as :"+inputFormat);              
        }

        log.error(exception);
        log.error("DateUtil.convertStringToDate :Parse exception while parsing,"+strDate+" using format :"+inputFormat);
        date = null;
    }
    return date;
}
```

I added the calendar part to somehow subtract 7hrs from the existing time. This doesn't work.

Comment: Show the other functions: `convertStringToDate`, `formatDate` (2-arg version).

Comment: FYI, "Please don't mark it down because I really need to solve this..." is a good way to get marked down. The onus is entirely on you to ask a good question, not on readers to forgive your mistakes.

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the calendar date before manipulating it:

```
cal.setTime(date);
```

before the:

```
cal.add( Calendar.HOUR, -7 );
```

And you seem to have some redundant code, like calling the Calendar getInstance twice.

Comment: It does subtract. Thanks Isac.

Answer (score 1):

You may change as following

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(displayDateString));
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -7);
```

> Though `new Date(displayDateString)` is deprecated function